# What does "dynamical symmetry of charge" mean?

Tags: charge, symmetry, terminology, definition

I was reading the following [Wikipedia article on charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_(physics)) and I encountered the following sentence:

> In the case of local, dynamical symmetries, associated with every charge is a gauge field; when quantized, the gauge field becomes a gauge boson.

What does "dynamical" mean in this context?